# An error has occurred. No resources were found when selecting for update

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365-operations, power-automate

I try to update MSCRM Account record in D365FO through Power Automate. When I run the flow, I get the error message.

> "message": "An error has occurred.  No resources were found when
>   selecting for update.

But When I set any one of the company(ex:10) to user,

I am able to update only 10 company related records using flow .Here I want to update all company related records(ex 10,11,12...etc).

Error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Error says resource not found probably record was not found.
Could you post screenshot of your flow It will really help understand more. Also should not be that difficult.

Comment: We have the record in F&O.I created using flow from crm to fo and trying to update same record.

Comment: ok please edit question and add screenshot of your flow, when and how it is firing what action it is performing. You mention in your question, you can update account 10 and not all how are your all accounts related?

Comment: I saw your screenshot. Few basic questions, Where have you built your flow? Try to buld your flow in Env from which you are firing (crm) you might have default as Env you might want to change it to your actual CRM env as this is your trigger. Also your object Id has 2 values to match, do you need 2 values, can you not match it with Account Nr only? and does your F&O has same customer group label available as coming from CRM.

Comment: I ran it using sys admin role and that is also in FO. Regarding Fo related fields, Object id should have the company name and account number.

Comment: What I can imagine, you do not get record with your match with object id you might want to look your matching criteria. I would suggest rather than giving dynamic object Id just for testing give static object Id manually and see if you can find f & o record because I am pretty sure you are not able to have correct object id.

Comment: I have tested using static values.No luck

Comment: How to change user company to global in FO?Any Idea

Comment: I tried to get list of records using "List Item Action". I have observed there is an option (Cross company=true) to get other company records as well. Is there any option (cross company =true) in update action as well.

Answer (score 0):

As we don't have option cross company =true on Update action,use Http action with Patch method.